# JQuery select element with certain children excluded

Tags: jquery

I am trying to use jquery to extract an html string from dom.

my page looks like

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="my-id1">first </div>
    <div id="my-id2">second </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I would like to get an html string looks like

```
 <html>
   <body>
     <div id="my-id2">second </div>
   </body>
 </html>
```

I know

```
$('html').not('#my-id1).html();
```

will not work because it will try to get an 'html' element and try to remove this element with id 'my-id1'.

Is there anyway to achieve what I want?

Thanks.

Comment: `$('div').not('#my-id1).html();`?

Comment: But I want the outside <html> and <body> tags too.

Comment: Ah, I missed that, sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can clone the html element and remove child element which you don't want

```
//Clone 
var elem = $('html').clone();

//Find first div and remove it
elem.find('#my-id1').remove();

//Get HTML
var html = elem.prop('outerHTML');
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/bK74d/)

Answer (score 1):

You have to clone it and then remove the unwanted part:

```
$('html').clone().find('#my-id1').remove();
```

The jQuery collection will now hold a clone to your original html, but without the my-id1 div.

Answer (score 0):

```
$( "#my-id1" ).remove();
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/somaberlin/9J96L/)